# How to serve an image from Express.js to React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, express

I am trying to serve up an image from my public directory on my node.js + express backend to the client side which is Reacts (create-react-app to be particular).

I have the typical file structure of

```
-public
   -images
      -image.jpeg
```

On my client side, I have an image tag with a relative path like so

```
<img src='/images/me.jpeg' alt="" />
```

My app.js for express looks like so

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const contactRouter = require('./routes/contact');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

//route handlers

app.use('/contact', contactRouter);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));
});


module.exports = app;
```

alas, I am not getting any luck with the image being served up. Any ideas for this? I am not sure if I also need an additional proxy for when I am in dev. I have tried this which likes in my src folder in react

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(proxy('/images/*', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
}
```

I appreciate the help guys!

Comment: Does your server have a build directory alongside your public folder like `/dist`?

Comment: No it does not have one. What specifically would the build folder do?

Comment: Not a problem. Theoretically though your code is correct and the image request should stop at the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));` and return the image if one exists at `/public/images/me.jpeg`

Comment: Hmm curious. If i were to look in the chrome dev tools, should I see a request being made to `localhost:5000/public/images/me.jpeg` from my <img> tag?

Comment: Ok, so I was able to find out that my img tag is making the req to localhost:3000/public/images/me.jpeg. So for whatever reason my proxy is not working

Comment: Ahh, im not familiar with proxies but everything else looks setup correctly